# Is there a way to split UI components e.g UIButtons into separate .swift file and then use them within the ViewController class in another .swift file

Tags: ios, swift

I want to declare all my UI components in a separate file than the main UIViewController class is in. So lets say this UIButton is located in UIComponents.swift file..

```
class UIComponents: UIView{

    var myButton : UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
}
```

I want to access it it ViewController.swift file in the following UIViewContoroller class and add it as a subview.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{

    self.view.addSubview(......)??
}
```

I am not sure if this is possible or even a good idea, any advice on this would help. I am trying to clean up my code and need help on the matter. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you can, and you should. You don't have to add the custom objects programatically, either--you can drag a generic UIView into your view controller in Interface Builder, and set its class to be your custom class.

Comment: I think he wants to hold the references to buttons in a separate class.

Comment: Yes, I want to hold reference to the buttons in a separate class. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Then put them in a separate class, have your view controller keep a reference to that separate class instance, and access the buttons via that reference. I don't know why that would be helpful, though.